# how to mask Image with other image and custom color

Tags: swift

I am trying to achieve something like this one
[image]

I already have these assets

[image]
[image]

I am using this code to mask the cover image but still, it doesn't take the color. so anyone can help me? I can do the required changes for the images if that necessary.

My code:

```
let mask = UIImageView(image: mask-img)
coverImage = UIImageView(image: cover-img)
coverImage.mask = mask
```

here is the result after using this code
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Mask View  is an "optional view whose alpha channel is used to mask a view’s content... Fully or partially opaque pixels allow the underlying content to show through but fully transparent pixels block that content." (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622557-maskview)

So you also need to add your mask view as a subview if you want it to be displayed, and it needs to have alpha not equal to one if you want the original view to be partially visible through it.